# How to exclude one file from packaging in Gradle (Android Studio)

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

We have to integrate 2 jars into our android app's dependency and unfortunately these 2 jars contains a same file in the META-INF/classes folder:

```
More than one file was found with OS independent path 'META-INF/classes/com.abc.efg.model.T'
```

I know in packagingOption there is a pickFirst command, so i tried:

```
packagingOptions {

  pickFirst 'META-INF/classes/com.abc.efg.model.T' 

}
```

But it still doesn't work.

Is there a way to specifically pick the first one into build from jar dependency?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried if excluding the file is working at least?

Comment: I have but we need that file to be included into the build path, otherwise it will have other errors if not.

Comment: have you tried with `pickFirst  'META-INF/*'`? If this doesn't work you probably have another problem

Comment: Where are you putting the `packagingOptions`?

Comment: I tried ```pickFirst 'META-INF/*'``` but it doesnt work, i put my ```packagingOptions ``` under ```android``` tag

Comment: `packagingOptions ` should be the solution, try to inspect if your path is really correct.